# siunitx: How do I unset options previously set with \sisetup?

Tags: siunitx, grouping

In the [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package (v1.3), I know that I can set various options with the `\sisetup` command. But what if I want a particular option to apply to only a small section of my document, with default behaviors for the rest of the document? How can I "unset" an option I have set and return to defaults?

Here is essentially what I'm trying to do:

```
Some text with SI units using default options.
\sisetup{prespace}
Some text with SI units using prespace option.
\sisetup{undo prespace, reset to default}
Some more text with SI units using default options.
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the scope of the command is to be limited to a single `table` environment, say, then issuing the command `\sisetup` *after* the `\begin{table}` statement (but before a `\begin{tabular}{...}` statement) will automatically achieve your goal.

More generally, you could confine the scope of the `\sisetup` command by "encasing" it in a pair of `\begingroup` ... `\endgroup` commands or, less visually intrusive, with a pair of curly braces -- `{` and `}`.

Separately, the current version of the `siunitx` package is **2.3**. If you're still working with version 1.3, as your question seems to indicate, you may want to consider upgrading the package to the latest version. :-)

Comment: All right, that works. It would still be nice if there were a way to reset default options with a command. But the functionality is what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: You may want to take up your issue with Joseph Wright, the author of the siunitx package and very active member (and moderator!) of this StackExchange group.

Answer (score 6):

A simple way would be to use `{}` to make a group which restricts changes to be within that group:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
{\sisetup{color = orange} 
5 \si{m^3}
}

\bigskip
5 \si{m^3}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In this case, \sisetup is not needed. One can use 5 \si[color = orange]{m^3} or, maybe even better \SI[color = orange]{5}{m^3}.

Comment: @toliveira: Yes, in _this_ [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301), it is simpler to specify the option. But, the question is about applying options to a "section of the document" and then unsetting them, hence the use of `\sisetup` instead of specifying all the desired options each time.